# Helm template function to detect node within values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I will try to reproduce a very strange behaviour (or my misunderstanding probably) of a helm template function which basically detects the existence of a node within values.yaml file. Actually is not so simple but it is the simplest way to show the problem:

I'm using *v2.16.1* helm version, but it is reproduced on newer 3.3.
Follow the next steps:

1. Create an example chart

> ```
> helm create myChart
> ```

2. Append the function to myChart helpers

> ```
> cat << EOF >> myChart/templates/_helpers.tpl
>
> {{- define "myChart.hasNodeA" -}}
>     {{- \$found := false -}}
>     {{- if .Values.A -}}
>         {{- \$found := true -}}
>     {{- end -}}
>     {{- print \$found -}}
> {{- end -}}
> EOF
> ```

(note the dollar escapes, that's only to ease you append the function with the *cat/EOF*)

3. Append the rendered condition within deployment:

> ```
> cat << EOF >> myChart/templates/deployment.yaml
> {{- if eq (include "myChart.hasNodeA" .) "true" }}
>   hasNodeA: "yes"
> {{- end }}
> {{- if eq (include "myChart.hasNodeA" .) "false" }}
>   hasNodeA: "no"
> {{- end }}
> EOF
> ```

4. Render without and with the node at values:

> ```
> helm template myChart | grep hasNodeA
> ```

This shows "no", and although it is "correct", it is because the function always returns 'false'

Adding the node:

> ```
> cat << EOF >> myChart/values.yaml
> A:
>   whatever: 555
> EOF
> ```

You will see the problem:

> ```
> helm template myChart | grep hasNodeA
> ```

**THIS SHOW "no" again.**

The thing is that the function condition is being fulfilled, indeed, if you test this one (edit the *_helpers.tpl* file moving the printout to the middle):

> ```
> {{- define "myChart.hasNodeA" -}}
>     {{- $found := false -}}
>     {{- if .Values.A -}}
>         {{- $found := true -}}
>         {{- print $found -}}
>     {{- end -}}
> {{- end -}}
> ```

You will see that the condition is really **passed**:

> ```
> $> helm template myChart | grep hasNodeA
> hasNodeA: "yes"
> ```

Obviously this does not work for negative cases.
The strange thing here is that the variable configured within the condition seems to be ignored when printed at the end.

Any idea about this behaviour ?
Thank U

Answer (score 1):

In Helm, the use of the operator `:=` creates a new variable inside its context. In this case, you are creating a new `$found` variable. In Helm v3 you can solve this using `=` operator.

If you're using Helm v2 then this will be solve using a lot of ifs.

BR

Comment: Ok, i tested "=" on helm2 (not helm3). As we are moving to helm3, i will test again as you said... Then, I assume that helm2 is very limited to face the situation.

Comment: Ok, finally works on helm3, so I think is enough for me. We have to use ":=" the first time, and then just asign (=):
{{- define "myChart.hasNodeA" -}}
    {{- $found := false -}}
    {{- if .Values.A -}}
        {{- $found = true -}}
    {{- end -}}
    {{- print $found -}}
{{- end -}}